# Error in using report viewer in visual studio 2012 in design mode

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

I'm using visual studio 2012 to develop a MVC application. I have added an ascx page to my project to put the report viewer in. When I drag and drop the ReportViewer component from toolbox in the page, It doesn't show the ReportViewer correctly and shows this error on it:

`Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms version 10.0.0.0, Culture=natural, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'`

I have also added Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms assembly to the project References. Is there anything wrong with reportviewer in Visual Studio 2012? Any help is appreciated in advance.

Comment: Microsoft.Reporting.WEBFORMS....does the webforms component work with MVC??

for more information check http://mvcrdlc.codeplex.com/

Comment: It does not work in Razor Views. But if you add an .ascx page to your project you can use it.

Answer (score 7):

SOLVED!

1. I downloaded and installed Report Viewer 2010 version.
2. Then  I added Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL assembly file from
   `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`.
3. And finally I added the following line to the .ascx file. `<%@
   Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,
   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
   namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>`

Comment: I didn`t find any file with the extension of .ascx

Comment: ASP.Net web forms have three types of files when your programming language is C#. .ascx, .ascx.cs and .ascx.designer.cs.

Answer (score 1):

> See in solution explore and explore the Reference link and remove ReportViewer Forms and WindowReportViewer then simple add the report viewer from toolbox, its works for me

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone as I found a very simple solution to this problem...

Go [HERE](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35747)
 and download the v11 of Reportviewer.

Then from the toolbox right click on general...
Click Choose Items and the browse to from the .NET Framework components `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`

That will add the ReportViewer to your toolbox!