# Generate report in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, reportviewer

I'm trying to generate a report but it is not displaying and in the html it is giving me the error message below.

```
Error Creating Control - ReportViewer1Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
```

html code

```
<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Report</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1 style="font-family: &quot;Austin 11pt&quot;; text-align: center">Returns Report</h1>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="600">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Web config

```
 <assemblies>
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="System.Net.Http.WebRequest, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Types, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.ProcessingObjectModel, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055601/error-in-using-report-viewer-in-visual-studio-2012-in-design-mode) [Check this aswell](https://forums.asp.net/t/1909800.aspx?Error%20Creating%20Control%20ReportViewer%20From%20VS2010%20to%20VS%202012)

1. downloaded and installed Report Viewer 2010 version.
2. add Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms.DLL assembly file from
   `C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms\11.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`.
3. And finally  add the following line to the .ascx file. `<%@
   Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,
   Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
   namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>`

Comment: I needed to add this <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="Report" %> to the html page but even after that the data is not showing