# Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer, Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm getting the error

> Failed to create designer 'Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ReportViewer,
>   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms' Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutal,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

I'm trying to add the report viewer from the toolbox and I get this error in the design view... looking for a way to fix this error. Please help.

web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.8"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.8"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb"
        type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:default /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>

</configuration>
```

Default.aspx

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="RDLCReport.Default" %>


<%@ Register assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms" namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" tagprefix="rsweb" %>




<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server">
        </rsweb:ReportViewer>
    </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error in using report viewer in visual studio 2012 in design mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16055601/error-in-using-report-viewer-in-visual-studio-2012-in-design-mode)

Comment: Look this bro: https://forums.asp.net/t/1909800.aspx?Error+Creating+Control+ReportViewer+From+VS2010+to+VS+2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure all other reportviewer nuget packages in your project are uninstalled as its version differences are the cause of this error. Clean and Rebuild project. Then

Download this nuget package - Install-Package Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms -Version 150.1400.0

Answer (score 0):

Do you have RDLC extension installed?

If not Visual Studio Top Menu >>> Extensions >>> Online >>> Search >>> RDLC